# How to pass parameter into variable in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

Is there anyway to do like this?

```
@echo off
ECHO WHAT do you want to do?
ECHO 1.MOVE
ECHO 2.COPY
set "Act="

IF %Act% EQU 1 SET process=MOVE ELSE SET process=COPY
%process% testfile.txt New
pause
```

Comment: Yes, that code will work once you correct a few minor typos; what's your question?

Comment: There are no typos actually. Syntax are correct

Comment: If the syntax was correct, you wouldn't be here asking the question :)

Comment: Bro I am not asking for syntax correction. I was asking the feature that I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
ECHO WHAT do you want to do?
ECHO 1.MOVE
ECHO 2.COPY
set /p "Act="

IF "%Act%" EQU "1" (SET "process=MOVE") ELSE (SET "process=COPY")
%process% testfile.txt New
pause
```

The `setlocal` makes sure that the environment changes made in the program (like setting `act` and `process` are discarded when the process ends, so the environment does not become contaminated with stale data.

the `/p` option to `set` means `accept input` implicitly from the keyboard but may also be from a file if redirected.

The quotes in the `if` ensure that each side of the comparison operator is non-null and interpreted as a single string if it contains separators like spaces.

The parentheses in the `if` are required (at least about the if-true part) in order that the `else` is not seen as a parameter to the potential executable in the if-true part.

The quotes in the plain `set` statements ensure that trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned (probably not actually required here, but it's a good idea to get used to doing that...you only need to be caught out once to waste a number of hours chasing stray spaces...)

Comment: thanks a lot,  I only failed to pass the "SETLOCAL" but the syntax of my code is legal

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your comment :(

Comment: @David - Perhaps I misunderstand. Yes, the syntax of your code is legal . However, it is not giving you the desired result. Is that correct?